# Dynamic Where Clause - Some variables not passing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I was wondering if the below scenario will work?  I am having trouble with it.

I have a smart tag SQLDataSource with a query like such:

```
    SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3] FROM [Table1] WHERE (@SubType = @SubID) ORDER BY [col1] ASC
```

No matter where or how I set the @SubType parameter, it does not work, yet if I change the query to `WHERE [col1] = @SubID` (removing the @SubType) it works fine.

Can I set a parameter as a field name to compare against like my query does?

Comment: This isn't really a good use case for the SqlDataSource Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how parameters work. Parameters are not string replacement. They work with values, not database objects names (Columns, Tables, etc.).

The solution is to first assemble the SQL query with the desired columns (code behind) and then set the parameter's values.

Comment: I ended up doing it in code behind via SQLDataReader. It was inside of a user control, so I set a public property to pass the variables, then bound it to my ListView.  Works great!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically replace the items in your `WHERE` clause then you will want to look at using [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), then you can build your SQL as a string and execute it.

Code sample from http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT O.OrderID, SUM(OD.UnitPrice * OD.Quantity)
               FROM   dbo.Orders O
               JOIN   dbo.[Order Details] OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
               WHERE  O.OrderDate BETWEEN @from AND @to
                 AND  EXISTS (SELECT *
                              FROM   dbo.[Order Details] OD2
                              WHERE  O.OrderID = OD2.OrderID
                                AND  OD2.ProductID = @prodid)
                GROUP  BY O.OrderID'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@from datetime, @to datetime, @prodid int',
                   '19980201', '19980228', 76
```

Another helpful link:

[Dynamic WHERE Clause](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-a-dynamic-where-clause)

Comment: but this is akin to eval in many other languages. I would avoid using this, as if you need to, you're propbably "doing it wrong".

Comment: @dwerner I agree, there are only some instances when you would need to use dynamic sql.  I am just showing an option.

Comment: NP, I just wanted to point out that it's not 'best' practice. I have a few examples of just this in a project I work on regularly, and I find them annoying. At least here you are using sp_executesql (+1)